# Javascript Youtube mp4 download to ios

Tags: javascript, ios, xcode, ios5, youtube

I searched for many solutions to play Youtube videos on iOS.
At the moment i just use a webview to show only the player and then press the play button (only embed the video in the webview).
But I know there is a javascript solution to get an mp4 link for the youtube video.

This is the javascript:
http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/25105

The script searches for the video element and grabs all informations and finally make it possible to download the mp4.
Im not good in javascript, so i dont know if there is an possibility to write that code, that it just works with http://myurl.com/getvideo?id=VIDEOID .

I would try it myself, but i dont know if it is possible to grab all these informations the script uses without the player element.

Maybe you can help me ;)

(im using iOS 5 btw)

My english is not the best, so if u have problems to understand something, just ask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can check [PSYouTubeExtractor](https://github.com/steipete/PSYouTubeExtractor) that allows you to retrieve the mp4 version of a YouTube video, it is pretty easy to use.